# Modular Arithmetic order of operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In an assignment, I am given $E_K(M) = M + K \pmod {26}$. This formula is to be applied twice in a formal proof, so that we have $E_a(E_b(M)) =\ ...$. What I'm wondering is; is the original given formula equal to $(M + K)\pmod{26}$, or $M + (K \mod{26})$? This will obviously make a big difference down the line.

I do suspect the first ($(M + K)\pmod{26}$), however I want to be certain before I move forward in my proof.

*NB: I did not tag this as homework as this is not actually part of the problem, rather just a clarification.*

Comment: The first (as in, $M+K\pmod{26}$ - just to be clear: this doesn't mean $M+K$ times $\pmod{26}$, which wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: Well, in the event of $M = 27$ and $K = 26$, they could both produce a different result; the first would be $(27 + 26) (mod\ 26) = 53\ mod\ 26 = 1$, the second would be $27 + (26 (mod\ 26)) = 27\ mod\ 26 = 27$. So to me, both do kinda make sense, which is why I ask... if you are certain, you can post that as an answer.

Comment: Are you aware of [mod as an operator vs. relation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101697/notation-for-modulo-congruence-relation-vs-operator)

Comment: @Julien: You’ve misunderstood Eric’s question. He’s asking whether it means *reduce* $M+K$ *modulo* $26$, or *reduce* $K$ *modulo* $26$ *and then add* $M$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh...

Comment: @Eric in your example, $27\equiv 1\pmod{26}$ so they produce the same result. The mod applies to all sides. Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Julien: No, in general they produce different results. See my answer.

Comment: Was confused by the second comment which the suggested the mod remained active *after* reducing K. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual interpretation of would be $E_K(M)$ is equal to $M+K$ if '$\text{mod}\: 26$' is applied to *both* sides. More generally, putting "$(\text{mod}\: N)$ to the right of a temr or equation usually applies to the whole equation or term. I.e., the following statements hold

$$\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& 1 + 4 \quad (\text{mod}\: 2) \\
2 &=& 6 + 2 \quad (\text{mod}\: 2).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Note that there's usually a wide blank before the $(\text{mod}\: N)$ term, like in the two equations above. In latex (and thus here) you can insert such a space with `\quad`. To make it absolutely clear that the equal sign *doesn't* mean normal equation, people also often use $\equiv$ (`\equiv`) instead of $=$. The above then becomes

$$\begin{eqnarray}
1 &\equiv& 1 + 4 \quad (\text{mod}\: 2) \\
2 &\equiv& 6 + 2 \quad (\text{mod}\: 2).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Interesting, my LaTeX-obsessed teacher used $=$, not $\equiv$, and there is not a big space before the $($. I transposed it exactly as she posted it. This is helpful, though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$M+K\pmod{26}$$

Your suggestion and use of brackets makes me want to clarify something (just in case):

$$E\equiv M+K\pmod{26}\iff E=M+K+26k,\;\;k\in\mathbb{Z} $$

The mod is not a variable you can operate on (not as written at least).

**Edit:** it appears I misread the question, although I suppose the $k$ relation above clarifies the order of operations anyway.

Comment: That *iff* statement is helpful, but you didn't quite get my question. Thanks for the answer anyway, though!

Comment: @Eric Yes, sorry about that. The way it was written I thought you were suggesting multiplication. My fault entirely (or perhaps I can blame it on the late hour...).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what is meant is $(M+K)\bmod 26$, where $\bmod$ is the operator, especially if this is in a cryptographic context. More careful writers reserve the parenthesized notation $\pmod{26}$ for the relation of congruence modulo $26$, using it only in connection with $\equiv$, as in $27\equiv 53\pmod{26}$.

Thus, if $M=K=27$, the intended result is probably $54\bmod 26=2$, not $27+(27\bmod 26)=28$.

Answer (score 1):

Without further context it is impossible to determine what is intended, because there are many abuses of the mod notation.

However, with high probability, the expression $\rm\: M\!+\!K\ (mod\ 26)\:$ denotes the remainder of $\rm\:M\!+\!K\:$ when divided by $26\,$ (or the entire residue class $\rm\ M\!+\!K+26\,\Bbb Z\:$ containing the remainder).

Your other possible interpretation, $\rm\:M + (K\ mod\ 26),\:$  is much more rare, though it does sometimes occur when discussing parity, e.g. authors may write $\rm\:n\ (mod\ 2)\:$ or $\rm\: n\ mod\ 2\:$ in arithmetical expressions that depend upon the parity of $\rm\:n.$

In the first case one is performing *modular* arithmetic, i.e. addition modulo $26$. In the second case one is performing *integer* arithmetic, i.e. normal integer addition. If the ambient context reveals which type of arithmetic is intended, then you can infer the meaning of the notation.

Comment: "... many abuses of the mod notation." That is absolutely the truth. If everyone would just use the notation correctly...